# How to load a HTML-page into a DIV by clicking a Li inside a menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i've came across a really annoying issue.

So, my plan is to have a UL-menu containing different ammounts of Li inside of it.
And when i click each of them i want to load a new HTML-page into my "Content-DIV".

I've done alot of research and i found out about Ajax and Jquery. I've tried so many different codes to make it work, and i've managed to link my .js file to my index file sucessfully. I tried it out with a simpel Alert command.
But then when i try to load my page into my DIV, it doesnt work at all, and i have no idea whats wrong!
I found a link here on stackoverflow which were almost the same, tho they didnt use a menu to open up the pages.

So here is my index:

```
<div id="Left">
    <ul id="nav" >
        <li><a href="Home.html id="load_home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">


</div>

<script>$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_home").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("Home.html");
    });
 });
</script>
```

Any ideas? Any answers would be much appreciated. 
Thank you.

/Martin

Comment: Is the home.html page just a html snippet or a full html page (<head><body>etc). BTW, this is a bad idea. If JavaScript is disabled then there is no navigation to your pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote the jQuery code in wrong manners Also please make sure  you've are calling jQuery library file.

### JavaScript code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

### HTML Code

```html
<div id="Left">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="page1.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html">Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">The page will display here</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you will try this code instead

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.get('Home.html', function(data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

well from your above code i couldn't see you have created any DIV with the ID : - content
So jquery is ok but from the above code i can say....jquery is not able to find the #content div.....

Please see below example which might help in your case : -

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="page1" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a id="page2" href="#">Community</a></li>
    <li><a id="page3" href="#">Sponsor</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="result" style="clear:both;">
</div>
```

At the head part, we need to include JQuery library.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add the following code to head part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#page1").click(function(){
        $('#result').load('pages/page1.html');
         //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
       }); 

       $("#page2").click(function(){
        $('#result').load('pages/page2.html');
         //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
       });
     });
</script>
```